# Extract name and prename from email address?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Question:
I have a table with the columns ID, Name, Prename, Mail

Mail contains the e-mail address of a person, for example john.doe@example.com

Now I need to check whether Name='' or Prename=''
and extract "John" from Mail and put it into Prename, and put "Doe" into column Name

Can i do that with SQL, if yes how ?

I use MS-SQL 2005

Comment: are the names always going to be separated by a "."?

Comment: There are some answers below that will solve your specific case, but as CSharpAtl's comment implies there is probably much more to it than that. Email addresses can be in many, many formats and name extraction can be a challenge. Think a lot about your specific requirements here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `UPDATE` statement as follows.

```
--relies on one and only one dot in the email account!
UPDATE  Customer
SET  PreName = LEFT(Email, CHARINDEX('.',Email)-1) --FirstName
     ,Name = SUBSTRING(Email,CHARINDEX('.',Email)+1, CHARINDEX('@',Email)-CHARINDEX('.',Email)-1)
```

To test this solution, try with a single string as a test.

```
--test it out with this script!
DECLARE @Addr varchar(100)

SELECT @Addr = 'humpty.dumpty@here.com'

DECLARE @DotAt int, @At int

SELECT @DotAT = CHARINDEX('.',@Addr)
       ,@At = CHARINDEX('@',@Addr)

SELECT  LEFT(@Addr, @DotAt-1), SUBSTRING(@Addr,@DotAt+1,@At-@DotAt-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You'll need to do some string manipulation. Check out the [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx), [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) and [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) functions.